# How to capture job queue details after completion in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

In Laravel 5.1, I would like to be notified when a job is completed, with details about the job (specifically, the `user_id`, and `customer_id`). I'm using the `Queue::after` method method in the `AppServiceProvider` as Laravel [suggests](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues).

If a dump the `$data` parameter like so:

```
Queue::after(function ($connection, $job, $data) {
    var_dump($data);
    exit;
});
```

I get the following:

```
array(2) { ["job"]=> string(39) "Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call" ["data"]=> array(1) { ["command"]=> string(263) "O:23:"App\Jobs\ExportContacts":4:{s:7:"*data";a:5:{s:7:"user_id";s:1:"2";s:10:"customer_id";s:1:"1";s:6:"filter";N;s:5:"dates";a:2:{i:0;i:1445352975;i:1;i:1448034975;}s:4:"file";s:31:"/tend_10-20-2015-11-20-2015.csv";}s:5:"queue";N;s:5:"delay";N;s:6:"*job";N;}" } }
```

The `data` array contains both of the `user_id` and the `customer_id`that I'm after.  Which is great.  But how do I parse this response to pull that information out.

My only thought is to use regex.  But I thought I'd check to see if there was a better way?

Answer (score 8):

For Laravel 5.2:

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
    $command = unserialize($event->data['data']['command']);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The data is serialized. You only have to:
`$command = unserialize($data['data']['command']);`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not need to get your data from `data`. I will show you simple use of Queue::later

```
$yourData = $data_which_you_need;

$date = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);

Queue::later($date, function($job) use ($yourData){
    // THIS CODE WILL BE EXECUTE AFTER 10 MINUTES
    $user_id = $yourData['user_id'];
    User::find($user_id)->destroy();
    $job->delete();
});
```

I hope that i help you

Comment: Thanks @alarmata.   But that would simply delay the execution of the job, correct?  I didn't necessary want it to be delayed, I just wanted to be notified when a specific job was done running, so I can execute other tasks upon completion...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to pull the variables that you passed to the job into the queue:after? Did you have to use regex? Even after unserializing its a massive string of data.

Still having trouble extracting data from the job that just ran into queue::after