# Unable to unserialize queue job data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this piece of code in my `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event)
{
    Log::info(unserialize($event->data['data']['command']));
});
```

It's simply a job event that triggers when a job has successfully executed (more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues), under "Job Events"). I got this solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37617100/6719559) question.

However, the above code gives me the error:

> 'ErrorException' with message 'Object of class App\Jobs\SampleJob could not be converted to string'

Here is the output of `$event->data`:

```
array (
  'job' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call',
  'data' => 
  array (
    'commandName' => 'App\\Jobs\\SampleJob',
    'command' => 'O:21:"App\\Jobs\\SampleJob":5:{s:10:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'post";O:45:"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier":2:{s:5:"class";s:18:"App\\Models\\Post";s:2:"id";i:28711;}s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";N;s:5:"delay";N;s:6:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'job";N;}',
  ),
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event)
{
    Log::info((array) unserialize($event->data['data']['command']));
});
```

This makes an array of attributes of the object, then logs it.

But just do this for debugging and such. To actually get properties of object, use `$obj->prop` notion.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `unserialize` method is an object, which cannot be converted to string directly.

Unserialize the event command first, then Log the object attributes one by one.